# Merge Json Object in form builder

Tags: json

I have two roles i-e, Admin & User. Admin have access to add dynamic field in form and the form is saved in json format and now user can access that form and input data in it and its also saved in json format.

My problem is that when admin edit the form and add a new field inside it, how can i tackle this.

For example, admin make a form that have Product name, Product detail and Product pics and now user can add 5 items in it using this form, after few time admin added one more field in form, that is Product Type and how can i add this field in users previous posts.

**Note:** Admin form and user submission is in json format but both are saved in separate tables.

Admin Form Builder
[image: Admin Form Builder]

Json of form builder and its save in form_sections table
[image: Json of form builder]

User View of form
[image: User View of form]

Users json is store in products table
[image: User Json]

when admin update form, json of form builder is updated but how i update the user json?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `Product` schema require your application to be [backward compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility).

That means your code should be able to deal with both new data(with `Product Type` field) and old data(without `Product Type` field).

Possible solutions:

1. Leave old product `Product Type` field empty, let user fill it later.
2. Loop through old product data and set `Product Type` field with a default value.

Comment: 1. Loop through old product data isn't the right solution because i have 3+ Million products. 
2. Leave old product field is empty is also not compatible for me because admin also have access to delete  any of input, if admin delete Product name input then this field is delete from all 3+ million products.

Comment: @umarAslam What's the name of this Form Builder? Where do you store these 3+ Million products, in a MySQL database?

Comment: I didn't used a built-in plugin because their is parent and child attributes, database attachment and relation are in that form builder and all built-in form builder doesn't meet with mine requirements.

Comment: @umarAslam Is this Form Builder system private and not public accessible? It may have take this scenario into account. Or you need to write a program to parse and modify the product data.

Comment: its a private form builder and i'm trying to write an efficient algorithm to change it quick.

Comment: @umarAslam I think following steps should do the work: read the data, parse json, set field, write data to db. It would be better to backup data and validate carefully before processing.

Comment: i think a new table is much more better than this, if admin adds or delete something their name would be saved in a table and it'll added when user edit their products.